# Connect Geth Node with my asics

Tags: go-ethereum, ethernodes, asics, stratum

I've looked all over the internet but couldn't find an answer.
So I've installed GETH and it's fully synced on my server. What is the easiest way to connect my asics and start solo mining. Do I need to create my own stratum server or is there a adress within geth that I can use ?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use ASICS to mine Ethers. That's because Ethereum uses a different mining algorithm (which demands a bunch of RAM memory) from Bitcoin and it was designed specifically to be ASICS resistant. Bitcoin uses SHA256 while Ethereum uses ETHASH.

If you want more info, there is [this excellent article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/what-is-the-difference-between-ethereum-and-bitcoin-mining-8bbd79bc96) by coinmonks.

Comment: There are ASICs to mine Ethereum https://2miners.com/blog/asic-miners-for-ethereum-antminer-e3-vs-innosilicon-a10-eth-master-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

what this will do is run the rpc server on your machine and your miner should be able to connect with it. Then you can connect your asic to geth with the url

```
http://localipgoeshere:8545
```